# iReport 3.6 não abre

Tags: java, ireport, jasper-reports

Eu e minha equipe trabalhamos com iReport, eu não tenho usado o meu já faz um tempo, mas precisei abri-lo para manutenção recentemente e ele não funciona. A splash screen exibe "*Loading cached objects*" e encerra o processo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri que o iReport 3.6 não funciona com o Java 1.8, desinstalei e voltou a funcionar imediatamente.

Agora estou usando o 1.7

Usei os 2 posts abaixo como referência, eles falam sobre o iReport 5.5.

[iReport 5.5.1 doesnt load](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825724/ireport-551-doesnt-load)

[iReport v5.5.1 execute error](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824912/ireport-v551-execute-error)

Comment: Se resolveu o problema marque como resposta correta, pois poderá ajudar a outras pessoas.

Comment: A resposta correta dada pelo próprio autor da pergunta demora um pouco @Jota, se não me engano é em torno de 24 horas.

Comment: Tem certeza sobre isso @maihe? Eu uso iReport 3.0 com jdk 8, e não me dá problemas.

Comment: Sim @GustavoCinque, eu me baseei em posts no JasperSoft Community, vou adicioná-los à resposta. E eu só posso marcar como correta depois de dois dias também.

Comment: Estranho esse aspecto então... Vou dar uma olhada no meu, de qlqr forma.

Answer (score 5):

acredito que a melhor solução não seja simplesmente desatualizar o java, no arquivo ireport.conf, localizado em "C:\Program Files\Jaspersoft\iReport-3.6.2\etc", basta incluir a configuração "jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\xjdk1.7.0_45", lembrando que tal JDK precisa está instalado, no meu caso renomei para xjdk1.7.0_45.

Answer (score 2):

Segue o exemplo do arquivo "ireport.conf" para versão 5.1.0.

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/5.1.0"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/5.1.0"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="--branding ireport -J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"

# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
#extra_clusters=
```

Onde "jdkhome" você indica o caminho da sua JDK.